# Is there a way to get Online status via PlayerId in Gamesparks

Tags: unity-game-engine, gamesparks

I have a saved list of my friends name and playerId via Gamesparks. I want to know if they are online/offline. Can I do that using their respective playerIds ?

Comment: `Spark.loadPlayer(myPlayerId).isOnline();`? from https://docs.gamesparks.com/api-documentation/cloud-code-api/player/sparkplayer.html#isonline Just a guess, I don't actually use Unity or Gamesparks, I just searched it.

Comment: @NathanMills That should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lookup a player's online status using their ID:

```
Spark.loadPlayer(myPlayerID).isOnline()
```

[`SparkPlayer` documentation](https://docs.gamesparks.com/api-documentation/cloud-code-api/player/sparkplayer.html#isonline)